# Source Request: Danish State in the Early Modern Period

Tags: discussion, source

*I'm hoping that the logic we had where source requests in Meta, i.e., questions which are open-ended, are okay is still valid.*

With that in mind, I am looking to find books relating to Denmark in 16th and 17th centuries which would work as good reference works, i.e., summarising the state of current research based on primary sources.

As a comparison, there are such works available for Sweden:

- J.A. Almquist, *"Den civila lokalförvaltningen i Sverige 1523–1630"*: covers the civilian administration of the state based on taxation records; essentially every taxation unit is mentioned and described;
- L.W. Munthe, *"Kungl. Fortifikationens Historia"*: covers the history of fortifications from the mid-16th century up until the 19th.

These are not "light" works: Almquist goes into four volumes which each have sub-volumes of their own; Munthe comes together at about seven volumes. As such, these forms very good reference works to start investigating a specific question and rely heavily on available primary sources.

To be clear, I am just using the Swedish examples as a description of what I am looking for.

Do similar works exist for Denmark?

Comment: I'm fairly sure they do but I'll have to do some digging so I'll try to get back to you on this.